# how to hide the filter in product listing page without modify the code base?

Tags: magento2, javascript, css, filter, product-listing

How to hide the filer in product listing page without touching the code?
Can I do it by CSS or javascript? Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For hide filter on specific category, please follow below steps:

1. After login admin side, go to Catalog > Categories
2. Select category and open Display Settings tab
3. Set No in Anchor field
4. Clear cache

Comment: this setting work for me, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Change the category design layout to `1 column` : this layout is sans filters.

*No code was harmed using this solution.*